# how to filter text file on the basis another text file

Tags: shell, regex, grep, cut

I have two text files. One is wordlist and another one is file to be filtered.

I want to remove or delete all the lines or links from the file if the line has any word from word list anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -vf wordlist file_to_be_filtered
```